# Retain DataFrame's index when using groupby apply to generate Series

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

When calling a function using `groupby` + `apply`, I want to go from a `DataFrame` to a `Series` groupby object, apply a function to each group that takes a `Series` as input and returns a `Series` as output, and then assign the output from the `groupby` + `apply` call as a field in the `DataFrame`.
The default behavior is to have the output from `groupby` + `apply` indexed by the grouping fields, which prevents me from assigning it back to the `DataFrame` cleanly. I'd prefer to have the function I call with apply take a `Series` as input and return a `Series` as output; I think it's a bit cleaner than `DataFrame` to `DataFrame`. (This isn't the best way of getting to the result for this example; the real application is pretty different.)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'A': [999, 999, 111, 111],
 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
 'C': [1, 3, 1, 3]
})
def less_than_two(series):
  # Intended for series of length 1 in this case
  # But not intended for many-to-one generally
  return series.iloc[0] < 2
output = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].apply(less_than_two)
```

I want the index on `output` to be the same as `df`, otherwise I cant assign
    to `df` (cleanly):

```
df['Less_Than_Two'] = output
```

Something like `output.index = df.index` seems too ugly, and using the `group_keys` argument doesn't seem to work:

```
output = df.groupby(['A', 'B'], group_keys = False)['C'].apply(less_than_two)
df['Less_Than_Two'] = output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) returns the results with the original `index`, just as you've asked for.  It will broadcast the same result across all elements of a group.  ***Caveat***, beware that the `dtype` may be inferred to be something else.  You may have to cast it yourself.

In this case, in order to add another column, I'd use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
df.assign(
    Less_Than_Two=df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['C'].transform(less_than_two).astype(bool))

     A  B  C Less_Than_Two
0  999  1  1          True
1  999  2  3         False
2  111  3  1          True
3  111  4  3         False
```

Comment: Looks like `transform` keeps the same `dtype` as the input field. I liked that `transform` keeps the original `Index`, although I'm not necessarily looking to broadcast here, which I guess doesn't matter because the results are of length 1. This answer is the best in spirit, although in the full problem `transform` converts `boolean` to `datetime`, which can't be converted back to `boolean`. Coming from R, I feel like the `Index` is a double-edged sword, and `dtypes` are kind of difficult, but I like a lot of other things.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `groupby` is necessary (and the resulting groupby object will have fewer rows than your DataFrame -- this isn't the case with the example data), then assigning the Series to the 'Is.Even' column will result in NaN values (since the index to `output` will be shorter than the index to `df`).

Instead, based on the example data, the simplest approach will be to merge `output` -- as a DataFrame -- with `df`, like so:

```
output = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].agg({'C':is_even}).reset_index() # reset_index restores 'A' and 'B' from indices to columns
output.columns = ['A','B','Is_Even'] #rename target column prior to merging
df.merge(output, how='left', on=['A','B']) # this will support a many-to-one relationship between combinations of 'A' & 'B' and 'Is_Even'
# and will thus properly map aggregated values to unaggregated values
```

Also, I should note that you're better off using underscores than dots in variable names; unlike in R, for instance, dots act as operators for accessing object properties, and so using them in variable names can block functionality/create confusion.

Comment: Thanks @cmaher. My example wasn't great; just updated. The intent to use use dataframe.groupby[field name].apply for series to series with same index, where the result will have the same shape as the input series, for many-to-many applications.

Comment: No problem. It's still unclear why you need a `groupby` at all; based on your description, and the sample code, you could create the `Less_Than_Two` column with `df.loc[:,'Less_Than_Two'] = df.C.apply(less_than_two)`

Comment: I'm a big fan of split-apply-combine, and `DataFrame` to `DataFrame` in `pandas` is pretty intuitive. In principle, I like to use the simplest data structure I can, so I want to do `Series` to `Series`, but the handling of `Index` is kind of throwing me. If this example came up in the the real world I'd probably just do `df.C < 2`, but the problem I'm working on is a bit different.